# Load jQuery in snippet and add elements to blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Disclaimer.* I am fairly new to JavaScript so if my workflow does not make sense at all or my vocabulary is yet not precise enough, please advise me of how I should do it differently.

**Current Approach**

I want to learn more about Javascript and external libraries. Thus, I created a snippet under the DevTools sources panel in Chrome, opened `about:blank` and executed the following code (which I copied and paste from different sources):

**Code**

```
(function(head) {
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
  newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
  newscript.async = true;
  newscript.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js";
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})(document.getElementsByTagName('head'));

function jQueryReady() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    my_code(jQuery);
  } else {
    setTimeout(jQueryReady, 100);
  }
}

jQueryReady();

function my_code($) {
  console.log("OK");
  $('head').append($('script', {
    type : 'text/javascript',
    async: true,
    src  : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.js'
  }));
  $('head').append($('link', {
    rel : 'stylesheet',
    href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.css'
  }));
}
```

**Results**

When I then look at the source code of `about:blank`, I see that the `jQuery` script is correctly inserted into the head, I see that the console shows `OK`, but neither the `spectrum` JavaScript nor the CSS is inserted into the head.

**Questions**

1. Why is the code not added to the HTML file? What do I need to change to make it work?
2. If I run teh code from `my_code` directly in teh console everything seems to work fine? Why?
3. What is a proper way of playing around with JavaScript **without** writing an own html file? Does the approach via snippet and `about:blank` make sense? I need to reload `about:blank` whenever I make changes to the snippet, so I guess there is a more elegant way to do so. Any tipps on how to do that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe it is because in jQuery, when you want to create new elements, it is necessary to wrap tag name in "<>" signs like this:

`$('head').append($('<script>', { 
      type: 'text/javascript',
      async: true, 
      src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.js'
}));`

3. In my opinion it is good idea to try sites like jsfiddle.net or codepen.io, where at least you can add libraries like jQuery easier without writing additional importing scripts and it is easier to maintain.